# AmazonSQSClientBuilder and AWSStaticCredentialsProvider with the Android SDK

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am attempting to implement message sending from my Android app using AWS SQS. I have included aws-android-sdk-core-2.6.15 and aws-android-sdk-sqs-2.6.15 jar files. With just these, I am unable to resolve AmazonSQSClientBuilder (import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClientBuilder) and AWSStaticCredentialsProvider (import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider).

These work if I include the aws-java-sdk-1.11.278 jar file. However, this causes the 'DuplicateFileException' when I try to build. If I include only this jar, then I get the 'GC overhead limit exceeded' error.

Is there a smaller package that will allow the import of these necessary classes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS SDK for Android does not follow the same pattern as AWS SDK for Java.

The applicable constructors can be found in these files depending on whether you want an async client or not:

- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-sqs/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQSAsyncClient.java
- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-sqs/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQSClient.java

One example:

```
AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = // Choose one of many classes that implement this for instance, CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider
AmazonSQSClient client = new AmazonSQSClient(awsCredentialsProvider);
```